# Jenkins mercurial plugin polling rules customization

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

Is there a way to configure jenkins [mercurial plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin) to poll only tags/branches matching a specific pattern? I.e. I need it to trigger a build only if a new tag with '**-dev**' suffix has been pushed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question

The field **Revision** in the [jenkins mercurial plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Mercurial+Plugin) is the same value one can use in `hg log -r <expression>` hence all of the expressions available [here](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/revsets) can be used

For example to find the latest **-dev** tag the following expression needs to be entered into the **Revision** field:

```
max(tag("re:\-dev$"))
```

Comment: Looks like this is working in the first place, but no manual build are possible and all commits that are no new tag matching the expression are failures. After first successful build jenkins tries to verify if new commits can be skipped in polling by filtering:

`$ hg ... --rev 'ancestors('max(tag("re:\-dev$"))') and not ancestors(XZY)' 
abort: unknown revision 'max(tag("re:\-dev$"))'!
ERROR: Failed to capture change log
java.io.IOException: Failure detected while running hg log to determine change log
at hudson.plugins.mercurial.MercurialSCM.determineChanges(MercurialSCM.java:668)`